# How can I check the list of numbers are in the range or not

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, range

I would like to validate the list of numbers are in the range or not.

if the list of numbers are smaller than 33 and bigger than 38, I want those numbers to be returned with their order.

```
i<-c(33,34,35,36,37,38,80,100)
for (i in 1:length(i)) {
  if ( 33 < i & i < 38 ) {
   next
  }
  print(i)
}
```

but it returns everything even though it shouldn't be

Comment: The for loop is indexed with a variable `i` but your vector is also called `i` so the index variable is overwriting the vector. Change one of the names.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much shorter version of what you are trying to do:

```
vec <- c(33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 80, 100)
vec[!vec %in% c(34:37)]
[1]  33  38  80 100
```

If you also want to correct your current code, then consider the following updated version:

```
for (i in 1:length(vec)) {
    if (33 < vec[i] && vec[i] < 38) {
        next
    }
    print(vec[i])
}
```

The major problems were that you were using the same variable `i` for both the vector of numbers and the dummy variable in your `for` loop.  Also, to `AND` together two logical conditions, you should use `&&`, not `&` (the latter which is the vectorized form of AND).

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your loop is indeed that you use `i` as both your vector name and your index variable. Here is a working version of your code with a renamed index variable

```
i<-c(33,34,35,36,37,38,80,100)
for (j in 1:length(i)) {
   if (! ( 33 < i[j] & i[j] < 38 )) {
       print(i[j])
   }
 }
```

By the way, here is a more compact way using the fact that R is vector-oriented:

```
indexes <- which(i > 33 & i < 38)
i[indexes]
```